# Java regex: difference between range and union

Tags: java, regex

Is there any difference practically between [a-zA-Z] and [a-z[A-Z]]?

According to java tutorial (and Pattern class javadoc):

```
[a-zA-Z]    a through z, or A through Z, inclusive (range)
[a-d[m-p]]  a through d, or m through p: [a-dm-p] (union)
```

[Java tutorial: character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)

Comment: Range is `a-z`, union of ranges is `[a-zA-Z]` which in Java can also be written as `[a-z[A-Z]]` or `[[a-z][A-Z]]`.

Comment: I suggest reading a better [article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#union), it is pretty thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Not much as far as I can see, other than making certain regexes easier to read. @hwnd's [link to the regexx article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#union) gives good examples.

I've come up with a fairly esoteric use-case that might warrant it though: a character-class builder. You could build a character class by wrapping any number of other character classes in `[]` and you wouldn't have to worry about stripping `[]` from the various constituent classes.

Comment: You probably mean `\p{Digit}`

Comment: `[\p{Digit}[^5]]` is a union.  It will end up matching everything.  If you want to match digits except 5, you would have to use an intersection `[\p{Digit}&&[^5]]`

Comment: Good point.  I shall wrack my brain to come up with a less-unuseful regex!