# Using Java regexes to match a range of Unicode code points _outside_ the BMP: it is possible at all?

Tags: java, regex, unicode

While totally unrelated at first, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26897498/1093528) made me wonder...

Java's regexes are based on `String`s; `String`s are sequences (arrays) of `char`s; and `char`s are ultimately UTF-16 code units.

The latter means that a single `char` can match any Unicode code point inside the BMP, ie from U+0000 to U+FFFF.

Outside the BMP however, two `char`s are required for a single code point (one for the leading surrogate, another for the trailing surrogate); from what I can see, apart from a dedicated grammar engine, I don't see a way for Java regexes (as defined by [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)) to define "character classes" for such code points, since there is no String literal for code points outside the BMP.

Notwithstanding that code *can* be written to produce regexes (well, string literals used as regexes) for such ranges, is there an existing mechanism in `Pattern` which is not documented and allows to do that?

Comment: Yes, if you have Java 7 or up, there's a `\x` option (look at the Javadoc for Pattern).  Otherwise, you need surrogate pairs.  Someone asked this a few days ago - I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: @DavidWallace uhwell, I have read the doc and missed that... Make it an answer!

Comment: Have a look at the excellent answer (not my one) here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26838867.  Your question isn't quite the same, but the answer is the same.  Should I close as a duplicate?

Comment: @DavidWallace indeed, an excellent answer; in fact I didn't even suspect that specifying a leading/trailing surrogate pair in a range would succeed!

Answer (score 8):

OK, so, answer to self; data extracted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26823484/1093528) and the associated [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838867) which [@DavidWallace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081110/david-wallace) pointed to.

It is possible. To paraphrase the answer, in such a character class as:

```
"[\uD83D\uDE01-\uD83D\uDE4F]"
```

the Java regex engine will be smart enough to notice that you specify a surrogate pair on both ends of the interval, and "compile" the regex accordingly.

In addition, **starting with Java 7**, you can also use `\x{foo}` where `foo` is the hexadecimal representation of the code point. Not forgetting the quoting necessary in Java string literals, the above can therefore be written:

```
"[\\x{1F601}-\\x{1F64F}]"
```

Comment: `smart enough to notice` To be precise, in Oracle's implementation, the engine converts the String into an array of `int` internally before it is compiled proper. Therefore, it simply sees `[codepoint]-[codepoint]` when compiling the character class, like the case with BMP.

Comment: @nhahtdh meh, blind copy and paste, didn't pay attention... Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Note for future readers: The Java regex engine isn't smart enough to handle this correctly if you negate the character class.

Comment: @flodin But it does work with the `\\x{1F601}` syntax.