# Java RegEx matcher breaks characters outside the BMP

Tags: java, regex, xml, supplementary

I'm currently writing a util class to *sanitize* input, that is saved to an xml document. Sanitizing for us means, that all illegal characters (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valid_characters_in_XML#XML_1.0) are just removed from the string.

I tried to do this by just using some regex, that replaces all invalid characters with an empty string, but for unicode characters outside the BMP, this seems to break the encoding somehow, leaving me with those `?` characters. It also does not seem to matter which way of replacing by regexp I use (`String#replaceAll(String, String)`, `Pattern#compile(String)`, `org.apache.commons.lang3.RegExUtil#removeAll(String, String)`)

Here's an example implementation with a test (in Spock), that shows the problem:
XmlStringUtil.java

```
package com.example.util;

import lombok.NonNull;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class XmlStringUtil {

    private static final Pattern XML_10_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\x{10000}-\\x{10FFFF}]"
    );

    public static String sanitizeXml10(@NonNull String text) {
        return XML_10_PATTERN.matcher(text).replaceAll("");
    }

}
```

XmlStringUtilSpec.groovy

```
package com.example.util

import spock.lang.Specification

class XmlStringUtilSpec extends Specification {

    def 'sanitize string values for xml version 1.0'() {
        when: 'a string is sanitized'
            def sanitizedString = XmlStringUtil.sanitizeXml10 inputString

        then: 'the returned sanitized string matches the expected one'
            sanitizedString == expectedSanitizedString

        where:
            inputString                                | expectedSanitizedString
            ''                                         | ''
            '\b'                                       | ''
            '\u0001'                                   | ''
            'Hello World!\0'                           | 'Hello World!'
            'text with emoji \uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFB' | 'text with emoji \uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFB'
    }

}
```

I have now a solution, where I rebuild the whole string from its single code points, but that does not seem to be the *correct* solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823484/replacing-emoji-unicode-range-from-arabic-tweets-using-java/26838867#26838867) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26897810/using-java-regexes-to-match-a-range-of-unicode-code-points-outside-the-bmp-it) a regex should work with "outside" characters. Are you sure it's not just a font problem?

Comment: I thought so too (at first), but the test says something different. It fails for the last entry of the where block.

Comment: These emojis fall into the forbidden range between D7FF and E000 and shouldn't get through at all.

Comment: If I insert spaces around them then the result is only the spaces. Therefore Java interprets the string different when writing them together. Even printing the codepoints from ``"\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFB"`` shows ``0x1f9d1`` and ``0x1f3fb``.

Comment: The emojis are valid XML. As you stated in the second post, they are in the allowed range 0x10000 to 0x10FFFF. This is also stated in the Wikipedia article.

Comment: I read about this unicode surrogate pair business and stand corrected. That lead to the working regex solution in my second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading and experimenting, a slight change to the Regex (replacing the `\x{..}` with the surrogates `\u...\u...` works:

```java
private static final Pattern XML_10_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
        "[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]"
    );
```

Check:

```java
sanitizeXml10("\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C\uDFFB").codePoints().mapToObj(Integer::toHexString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

results in

```
1f9d1
1f3fb
```

Comment: Ok, this was basically it. Strangely I had to remove all escapes from the _character point groups_ but was not allowed to do remove them from the single character points. So the working RegEx is `[^\u0009\u000A\u000D -퟿-�-]`

Answer (score 1):

A solution without regex could be a filtered code point stream:

```java
public static String sanitize_xml_10(String input) {
    return input.codePoints()
            .filter(Test::allowedXml10)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new,StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();
}

private static boolean allowedXml10(int codepoint) {
    if(0x0009==codepoint) return true;
    if(0x000A==codepoint) return true;
    if(0x000D==codepoint) return true;
    if(0x0020<=codepoint && codepoint<=0xD7FF) return true;
    if(0xE000<=codepoint && codepoint<=0xFFFD) return true;
    if(0x10000<=codepoint && codepoint<=0x10FFFF) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's basically what I did. And it works. But it feels strange, that it is not possible to do this on String level already..